# Error while creating a new component in angular app

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, nrwl-nx, nrwl, nx-devkit

[image]

This error is showing when I try to run `nx g c @nrwl/angular:app Admin` to create a component in my angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just using a wrong syntax.
`nx g @nrwl/angular:app Admin`
This is the correct command to create an app in a project based on nx angular.